# Shuffle a pandas dataframe by groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shuffle

My dataframe looks like this

```
sampleID  col1 col2
   1        1   63
   1        2   23
   1        3   73
   2        1   20
   2        2   94
   2        3   99
   3        1   73
   3        2   56
   3        3   34
```

I need to shuffle the dataframe keeping same samples together and the order of the col1 must be same as in above dataframe.

So I need it like this

```
sampleID  col1 col2
   2        1   20
   2        2   94
   2        3   99
   3        1   73
   3        2   56
   3        3   34
   1        1   63
   1        2   23
   1        3   73
```

How can I do this? If my example is not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you want to shuffle by `sampleID`. First `df.groupby`, shuffle (`import random` first), and then call `pd.concat`:

```
import random

groups = [df for _, df in df.groupby('sampleID')]
random.shuffle(groups)

pd.concat(groups).reset_index(drop=True)

   sampleID  col1  col2
0         2     1    20
1         2     2    94
2         2     3    99
3         1     1    63
4         1     2    23
5         1     3    73
6         3     1    73
7         3     2    56
8         3     3    34
```

You reset the index with `df.reset_index(drop=True)`, but it is an optional step.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `np.random.shuffle(groups)` ?

Comment: @agcala random.shuffle is better suited for shuffling lists of objects (dfs).

Comment: What's the _ in `[df for _, df in df.groupby('sampleID')]`?

Comment: Does `[df for df in df.groupby('sampleID)]` not achieve the same thing?

Comment: @AMerii iterating over grouoBy yields a tuple of (index, group). Since we don't need the index we can use the "don't care var" _ to assign it to and do nothing with it.

Answer (score 10):

I found this to be significantly faster than the accepted answer:

```py
ids = df["sampleID"].unique()
random.shuffle(ids)
df = df.set_index("sampleID").loc[ids].reset_index()
```

for some reason the `pd.concat` was the bottleneck in my usecase. Regardless this way you avoid the concatenation.

Comment: Excellent solution.  One minor difference compared to the accepted answer is you can recover the original index.  This actually turned out to be useful for my purposes (even though not part of OP's question).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one thing to @cs95 answer. 
**If you want to shuffle by `sampleID` but you want to have your `sampleIDs` ordered from 1.** So here the `sampleID` is not that important to keep.
Here is a solution where you have just to iterate over the gourped dataframes and change the `sampleID`.

```
groups = [df for _, df in df.groupby('doc_id')]

random.shuffle(groups)

for i, df in enumerate(groups):
     df['doc_id'] = i+1

shuffled = pd.concat(groups).reset_index(drop=True)

        doc_id  sent_id  word_id
   0       1        1       20
   1       1        2       94
   2       1        3       99
   3       2        1       63
   4       2        2       23
   5       2        3       73
   6       3        1       73
   7       3        2       56
   8       3        3       34
```