# Is it possible to shuffle a dataframe while using while grouping by index in pandas or sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have dataframe df, containing patient data, as shown below:

```
| patient_id    | x     | y     | path  | target    |
|------------   |-----  |-----  |------ |--------   |
| 4423          | 234   | 53    | ....  | 1         |
| 4423          | 259   | 68    | ....  | 0         |
| ...           | ...   | ...   | ...   | ...       |
| 3351          | 100   | 34    | ....  | 1         |
| 3351          | 150   | 78    | ....  | 1         |
```

What I would like to do is shuffle the data while maintaining the patient_id order. In other words, I want to `df.groupby('patient_id')` and then shuffle my data.

Is there a way to achieve this using pandas or sklearn?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585860/shuffle-a-pandas-dataframe-by-groups helps?

Comment: Yes, I'm reading it right now, trying to wrap my mind around it. :D

Comment: @Pygirl I implemented the solution and it worked fine, but I don't understand what happened here: `[df for _, df in df.groupby('sampleID')]` , could you perhaps break it down for me? I understand list comprehension but I have never seen it used in this way before.

Comment: We are shuffling subset of dataframes created using groupby. 
https://ctxt.io/2/AABANXVKEg

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I don't understand the syntax that is used.

Comment: Is it the same as using `[df for df in df.groupby('sampleID')]`?

Comment: Nope it will give you index too, like if your groupby creates 3 chunks then index will be from 1 to 3. It's like keeping the note of chunks of dataframe created.